# Macos VSCode doesn't run some extensions

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am more Intelij user.
I've installed some plugins for VScode: "Learn Vim", "Import Intelij Keybindings".
However when I try to run this plugins from pallete nothing is occurring.
I am capable to change theme from the command pallete but can't run extentions.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your VSCode?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to restart VSCode, and tried to restart mac